# Swift and Curl and SAML

Tags: swift, saml

I am building a macOS app that needs to log into an Alfresco site (content management) using SAML. I'm using Curl and a function that'll run shell scripts to make the calls. I'm new to SAML and have been following this site to bandage together my program:

https://www.ssocircle.com/en/developer-tutorial-saml-testing-using-curl-and-ssocheck-api/developer-tutorial-part-i-a-saml-sso-flow-from-the-command-line-with-curl/

I make the initial call and am able to get the 302 redirect. From that HTML I am able to get the submission form and retrieve the url, SAML request and relay state. I make a call with those:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -b cookie -c cookie --request POST SAMLResponse="\(strSAMLRequestVal)" --data-urlencode RelayState="\(strSAMLRelayStateVal)" \(strSAMLURL)
```

but each time I get an error response:

```
<h3>ERROR</h3>
    <p>
       An error occurred while processing your request.  Please contact your helpdesk or
       user ID office for assistance.
    </p>
    <p>
       This service requires cookies. Please ensure cookies are enabled in your browser,
       then go back to your desired resource and try to login again.
    </p>
    <p>
       Use of your browser's back button may cause specific errors that can be resolved by
       going back to your desired resource and trying to login again.
    </p>
    <p>
       If you think you were sent here in error,
       please contact technical support
    </p>       
    
    <strong>Error Message: Error decoding authentication request message</strong>
```

so a couple of questions:

Am I going about this correctly? How can I store cookie data in a Swift macOS app? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use an URLSession/URLrequest for making that request instead of calling a curl method?

Comment: Because when I tried URLSession the response I kept getting was the SAML form to validate my authentication, it wouldn't take me through to the endpoint. If I took the url from the response and plugged it into a browser, it continued through the validation and displayed the json I was expecting.